Android icon change
Have two app sender and takes from sender send message to app takes but without opening app takes just take message and will app takes change app icon
I was trying broadcast and app takes I checked from logd he take message but no change icon app how can change app icon without opened

App icon change isn't possible without an app restart. Also post the relevant code, otherwise no one will be able to help you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

this url have my problem with the code please if anyone know solution tell me tue url : https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78626171
